# How to use [seq] in Pure Data?

Tags: puredata

I want to playback and manipulate a MIDI file in Pure Data using the library Cyclone's command [seq].
As I'm unable to find docs to cyclone, I've come her to ask for help.
Pls help.

Comment: https://forum.pdpatchrepo.info/topic/13012/cyclone-play-midi-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cyclone is an exceptionally well documented library. If you can't find the helpfile for it there is something wrong with your installation.

[image: Screenshot of seq helpfile]